# How to sort data based on the value of a column for part (multiple lines) of a file?

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

My data in the file `file1` look like

```
3
0
2 0.5
1 0.8
3 0.2
3
1
2 0.1
3 0.8
1 0.4
3
2
1 0.8
2 0.4
3 0.3
```

Each block has the same number of rows (Here it is 3+2 = 5). In each block, the first two lines are header, the next 3 rows have two columns, the first column is the label, which is one of the number from 1 to 3. I want to sort the rows in each block, based on the value of the first column (except the first two rows). So the expected result is

```
3 
0
1 0.8
2 0.5
3 0.2
3
1
1 0.4
2 0.1
3 0.8
3
2
1 0.8
2 0.4
3 0.3
```

I think `sort -k 1 -n file1` will be good for the total file.
It gives me the wrong result:

```
0
1
2
3
3
3
2 0.1
3 0.2
3 0.3
1 0.4
2 0.4
2 0.5
1 0.8
1 0.8
3 0.8
```

This is not the expected result.

How to sort each block is still a problem for me. I think AWK is possible to perform this problem. Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the DSU (Decorate/Sort/Undecorate) idiom using any awk+sort+cut and regardless of how many lines are in each bock:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NF<pNF || NR==1 { blockNr++ }
    { print blockNr, NF, NR, (NF>1 ? $1 : NR), $0; pNF=NF }
' file |
sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k4,4 -k3,3 |
cut -f5-
3
0
1 0.8
2 0.5
3 0.2
3
1
1 0.4
2 0.1
3 0.8
3
2
1 0.8
2 0.4
3 0.3
```

To understand what that's doing, just look at the first 2 steps:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF<pNF || NR==1{ blockNr++ } { print blockNr, NF, NR, (NF>1 ? $1 : NR), $0; pNF=NF }' file
1       1       1       1       3
1       1       2       2       0
1       2       3       2       2 0.5
1       2       4       1       1 0.8
1       2       5       3       3 0.2
2       1       6       6       3
2       1       7       7       1
2       2       8       2       2 0.1
2       2       9       3       3 0.8
2       2       10      1       1 0.4
3       1       11      11      3
3       1       12      12      2
3       2       13      1       1 0.8
3       2       14      2       2 0.4
3       2       15      3       3 0.3
```

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF<pNF || NR==1{ blockNr++ } { print blockNr, NF, NR, (NF>1 ? $1 : NR), $0; pNF=NF }' file |
    sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k4,4 -k3,3
1       1       1       1       3
1       1       2       2       0
1       2       4       1       1 0.8
1       2       3       2       2 0.5
1       2       5       3       3 0.2
2       1       6       6       3
2       1       7       7       1
2       2       10      1       1 0.4
2       2       8       2       2 0.1
2       2       9       3       3 0.8
3       1       11      11      3
3       1       12      12      2
3       2       13      1       1 0.8
3       2       14      2       2 0.4
3       2       15      3       3 0.3
```

and notice that the `awk` command is just creating the key values that you need for `sort` to sort on by block number, line number or $1, etc. So `awk` Decorates the input, `sort` Sorts it, and `cut` Undecorates it by removing the decoration values that the `awk` script added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` and arrays in gawk

```
awk 'NF==1 && a[1]{
        n=asort(a); 
        for(k=1; k<=n; k++){print a[k]}; 
        delete a; i=1
    }NF==1{print}
    NF==2{a[i]=$0;++i}
    END{n=asort(a); for(k=1; k<=n; k++){print a[k]}}
' file1
```

you get

```
3
0
1 0.8
2 0.5
3 0.2
3
1
1 0.4
2 0.1
3 0.8
3
2
1 0.8
2 0.4
3 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Ed Morton's solution but without variable assignment, it uses only built-in variables instead:

```
λ cat input.txt 
3
0
2 0.5
1 0.8
3 0.2
3
1
2 0.1
3 0.8
1 0.4
3
2
1 0.8
2 0.4
3 0.3
```

```sh
awk '{ print int((NR-1)/5), ((NR-1)%5<2) ? 0 : 1, (NF>1 ? $1 : NR), NR, $0 }' input.txt |
  sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 | cut -d ' ' -f5-
```

```
3
0
1 0.8
2 0.5
3 0.2
3
1
1 0.4
2 0.1
3 0.8
3
2
1 0.8
2 0.4
3 0.3
```

How it work

```sh
awk '{ print int((NR-1)/5), ((NR-1)%5<2) ? 0 : 1, (NF>1 ? $1 : NR), NR, $0 }' input.txt
```

```
0 0 1 1 3
0 0 2 2 0
0 1 2 3 2 0.5
0 1 1 4 1 0.8
0 1 3 5 3 0.2
1 0 6 6 3
1 0 7 7 1
1 1 2 8 2 0.1
1 1 3 9 3 0.8
1 1 1 10 1 0.4
2 0 11 11 3
2 0 12 12 2
2 1 1 13 1 0.8
2 1 2 14 2 0.4
2 1 3 15 3 0.3
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you! I feel ashamed I didn't notice that. I fixed my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. The only remaining issue is it's using a hard-coded 5 lines block size when the OP said `Each block has the same number of rows (Here it is 3+2 = 5)` which to me suggests the block size isn't always 5. You COULD make the 5 variable but then the user would need to set it manually so it'd be better to just figure out the block size from reading [part of] the input.

Answer (score 1):

A ruby:

```
ruby -e '$<.read.split(/\n/).map(&:split).
         slice_when { |a, b| b.length == 1 && b.length < a.length }.
         map{|e| e.sort_by{|sl| sl.length()>1 ? -sl[-1].to_f : -1.0/0}}.
         each{|e| e.each{|x| puts "#{x.join(" ")}"}}' file
```

Or, a [DSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) form ruby:

```
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{lines=[]; block=0; lnf=0}
            block+=1 if $F.length()>1 && lnf==1
            lnf=$F.length()
            lines << [block, -($F.length()>1 ? $F[-1].to_f : (-1.0/0)), $.] + $F
            END{lines.sort().each{|sl| puts "#{sl[3..].join(" ")}"}}
' file
```