# How to fix Bad File descriptor in a Sed Command in unix

Tags: awk, sed, descriptor

I have a source file that has all many group numbers (assume its a key field) with related data. I am using awk and sed command to create separate files based on the group number found in the source file.

I am doing like below. My Output is as expected but am getting below warning when running the command.

```
sed: couldn't close stdout: Bad file descriptor
```

Code:

```
awk -F, '{print  $2FS$3FS$6FS$4FS$43FS$44FS$5FS$7FS$8FS$9FS$10FS$11FS$12FS$13FS$14FS$15FS$16FS$17FS$18FS$19FS$20FS$21FS$22FS$23FS$24FS$25FS$26FS$27FS$28FS$29FS$30FS$31FS$32FS$33FS$34FS$35FS$36FS$37FS$38FS$39FS$40FS$41FS$42FS$45> $1 }'
for i in *.csv; do
    sed -i -e  "1 i\RECORD_TYPE,GROUP_NO,ACCOUNT_NO,EMPLOYEE_SSN,CARS_ERROR_CODE,CARS_ERROR_DESC,NEW_PARTICIPANT_ID,DEPENDENT_SSN,EFFECTIVE_DATE,DEPENDENT_SEQ_NO,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_INITIAL,ADDRESS_LINE_1,ADDRESS_LINE_2,ADDRESS_LINE_3,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,RELATIONSHIP_CODE,DATE_OF_BIRTH,SEX_CODE,SMOKER_INDICATOR,HIRE_DATE,LOCATION_NO,LOCATION_DATE,REPORTED_SALARY,SALARY_MODE,SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE,WEEKLY_HOURS,PRODUCT_ID,TERMINATION_DATE,TERM_REASON_CODE,COVERAGE_OPTION,PLAN_CODE,UNITS,PRODUCT_SET_ID,UNDERWRITING_STATUS_IND,APPLICATION_RECEIVED_DATE,CERTIFICATE_NO,STATUS_TYPE,FILE_ID,FILE_DATE,CARS_DATE"  $i
done
```

Comment: Always copy/paste your shell script(s) into https://shellcheck.net and fix the problems that tool tells you about before posting here if you still have a problem afterwards. Please also read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Comment: Sure Thank you Ed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not simply print the header from the Awk script when you create a new file?

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
{ if (!a[$1]++)
    print "RECORD_TYPE", "GROUP_NO", "ACCOUNT_NO", "EMPLOYEE_SSN", \
     "CARS_ERROR_CODE", "CARS_ERROR_DESC", "NEW_PARTICIPANT_ID", \
     "DEPENDENT_SSN", "EFFECTIVE_DATE", "DEPENDENT_SEQ_NO", \
     "LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME", "MIDDLE_INITIAL", "ADDRESS_LINE_1", \
     "ADDRESS_LINE_2", "ADDRESS_LINE_3", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIPCODE", \
     "RELATIONSHIP_CODE", "DATE_OF_BIRTH", "SEX_CODE", "SMOKER_INDICATOR", \
     "HIRE_DATE", "LOCATION_NO", "LOCATION_DATE", "REPORTED_SALARY", \
     "SALARY_MODE", "SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE", "WEEKLY_HOURS", "PRODUCT_ID", \
     "TERMINATION_DATE", "TERM_REASON_CODE", "COVERAGE_OPTION", "PLAN_CODE", \
     "UNITS", "PRODUCT_SET_ID", "UNDERWRITING_STATUS_IND", \
     "APPLICATION_RECEIVED_DATE", "CERTIFICATE_NO", \
     "STATUS_TYPE", "FILE_ID", "FILE_DATE", "CARS_DATE" >$1
  print $2, $3, $6, $4, $43, $44, $5, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, \
    $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, \
    $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, \
    $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $45> $1 }'
```

Perhaps notice also the `OFS=FS` so you can use a simple comma instead of `FS`.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk to handle many simultaneously open output files:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        for (i=8; i<=42; i++) fldNrs = fldNrs FS i
        nf = split("2,3,6,4,43,44,5" fldNrs ",45",out2in)
        split("RECORD_TYPE,GROUP_NO,ACCOUNT_NO,EMPLOYEE_SSN,CARS_ERROR_CODE,CARS_ERROR_DESC,NEW_PARTICIPANT_ID,DEPENDENT_SSN,EFFECTIVE_DATE,DEPENDENT_SEQ_NO,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_INITIAL,ADDRESS_LINE_1,ADDRESS_LINE_2,ADDRESS_LINE_3,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,RELATIONSHIP_CODE,DATE_OF_BIRTH,SEX_CODE,SMOKER_INDICATOR,HIRE_DATE,LOCATION_NO,LOCATION_DATE,REPORTED_SALARY,SALARY_MODE,SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE,WEEKLY_HOURS,PRODUCT_ID,TERMINATION_DATE,TERM_REASON_CODE,COVERAGE_OPTION,PLAN_CODE,UNITS,PRODUCT_SET_ID,UNDERWRITING_STATUS_IND,APPLICATION_RECEIVED_DATE,CERTIFICATE_NO,STATUS_TYPE,FILE_ID,FILE_DATE,CARS_DATE",outHdrs)
    }
    { out = $1 ".csv" }
    !seen[$1]++ {
        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", outHdrs[i], (i<nf ? OFS : ORS) > out
        }
    }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", $(out2in[i]), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS) > out
        }
    }
' file
```

With other awks it'd be more efficient and robust to apply a DSU (Decorate/Sort/Undecorate) algorithm, e.g. using any awk, sort, and cut:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1, NR, $0}' file |
sort -t',' -k1,1 -k2,2n |
cut -d',' -f3- |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        for (i=8; i<=42; i++) fldNrs = fldNrs FS i
        nf = split("2,3,6,4,43,44,5" fldNrs ",45",out2in)
        split("RECORD_TYPE,GROUP_NO,ACCOUNT_NO,EMPLOYEE_SSN,CARS_ERROR_CODE,CARS_ERROR_DESC,NEW_PARTICIPANT_ID,DEPENDENT_SSN,EFFECTIVE_DATE,DEPENDENT_SEQ_NO,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_INITIAL,ADDRESS_LINE_1,ADDRESS_LINE_2,ADDRESS_LINE_3,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE,RELATIONSHIP_CODE,DATE_OF_BIRTH,SEX_CODE,SMOKER_INDICATOR,HIRE_DATE,LOCATION_NO,LOCATION_DATE,REPORTED_SALARY,SALARY_MODE,SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE,WEEKLY_HOURS,PRODUCT_ID,TERMINATION_DATE,TERM_REASON_CODE,COVERAGE_OPTION,PLAN_CODE,UNITS,PRODUCT_SET_ID,UNDERWRITING_STATUS_IND,APPLICATION_RECEIVED_DATE,CERTIFICATE_NO,STATUS_TYPE,FILE_ID,FILE_DATE,CARS_DATE",outHdrs)
    }
    $1 != prev {
        close(out)
        out = $1 ".csv"
        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", outHdrs[i], (i<nf ? OFS : ORS) > out
        }
        prev = $1
    }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", $(out2in[i]), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS) > out
        }
    }
'
```

For more info on DSU see [How to sort data based on the value of a column for part (multiple lines) of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367).