# How can I remove duplicates only once an X number of occurrences is reached with awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I know how to use awk to remove duplicate lines in a file:

`awk '!x[$0]++' myfile.txt`

But how can I remove the duplicates only if there are more than two occurrences of this duplicate?

For example:

```
apple
apple
banana
apple
pear
banana
cherry
```

would become:

```
banana
pear
banana
cherry
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts could you please post  samples of input and output to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I have just edited my example.

Comment: Do you care about retaining input order?

Comment: Actually I kind of do, yes, otherwise I think I could have used a combination of ```sort```and ```uniq```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
apple
apple
banana
apple
pear
banana
cherry
```

then

```
awk 'FNR==NR{cnt[$0]+=1;next}cnt[$0]<=2' file.txt file.txt
```

gives output

```
banana
pear
banana
cherry
```

Explanation: This is 2-pass approach. `FNR=NR` (current file number of row equal to total number of row) does hold true only for 1st file, here I simply count number of occurences in `file.txt` by increasing (`+=`) value in array `cnt` under key being whole line (`$0`) by `1` then I instruct GNU `AWK` to go to `next` line as I do not want to do anything else. After that only lines which fullfill number of occurrences is less or equal two are outputed. Note: `file.txt file.txt` is intentional.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: It works, thanks a lot Daweo, especially for the explanations, as they really help me understand awk (I'm new to it, obviously...)! Can I go so far as to ask you how I would do if I wanted to export the deleted duplicates in a separate file? All in all, thanks a lot again!

Comment: nbd but `cnt[$0]+=1` = `cnt[$0]++`

Comment: hmmm why does your solution specifically require *gnu* awk ? looks rather portable to me.

Comment: Thank you very much once again Ed Morton! : )

Comment: RARE Kpop Manifesto, I don't necessarily need awk specifically, but I just knew how to remove duplicates with it, so I figured I'd learn how to tweak it to be more specific. Can I ask what you mean by 'portable'? Isn't awk the most adapted solution for this problem? I'm learning about bash, so any suggestion/advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about output order, this would do what you want without reading the whole file into memory in awk:

```
$ sort file | awk '
    $0!=prev { if (cnt<3) printf "%s", vals; prev=$0; cnt=vals="" }
    { vals=vals $0 ORS; cnt++ }
    END { if (cnt<3) printf "%s", vals }
'
banana
banana
cherry
pear
```

The output of `sort` has all the values grouped together so you only need to look at the count when the values change to know how many of the previous value there were. `sort` still has to consider the whole input but it's designed to handle massive files by using demand paging, etc. and so is far more likely to be able to handle huge files than reading it all into memory in awk.

If you do care about output order you could use a DSU approach, see [How to sort data based on the value of a column for part (multiple lines) of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367)

Comment: Oh, this is super interesting, thanks! It may actually be handy, as I have to deal with quite big files sometimes! Can I ask why this solution does not read everything into memory? (thanks a lot for the help everyone, again!)

Comment: Is it because instead of going through everything once to keep track of the number of duplicates, it simply discards duplicates once a certain threshold has been reached, thus not updating the stored number of duplicates?

Comment: Indeed, thank you so much for taking time to explain this! : )

Comment: You're welcome. I moved my explanatory comment into the answer and will delete it now.