# I want to date sort the 5th col using sort command.But the problem is no consistency in format,what can be the way to do it?

Tags: linux, awk

```
M_ID,M_NAME,DEPT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,Salary 
M001,Richa,D001,27-Jan-07,27-Feb-07,150000 
M002,Nitin,D002,16-Feb-07,16-May-07,40000 
M003,AJIT,D003,8-Mar-07,8-Sep-07,70000 
M004,SHARVARI,D004,28-Mar-07,28-Mar-08,120000 
M005,ADITYA,D002,27-Apr-07,27-Jul-07,40000 
M006,Rohan,D004,12-Apr-07,12-Apr-08,130000 
M007,Usha,D003,17-Apr-07,17-Oct-07,70000 
M008,Anjali,D002,2-Apr-07,2-Jul-07,40000 
M009,Yash,D006,11-Apr-07,11-Jul-07,85000 
M010,Nalini,D007,15-Apr-07,15-Oct-07,9999
```

```
 tail -10 Joining_date.txt|awk -F\, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5|("sort -t, -M");$6} '
```

Expected output

```
M001,Richa,D001,27-Jan-07,27-Feb-07,150000
M002,Nitin,D002,16-Feb-07,16-May-07,40000
M008,anjali,D002,2-Apr-07,2-Jul-07,40000
M009,Yash,D006,11-Apr-07,11-Jul-07,85000
M005,ADITYA,D002,27-Apr-07,27-Jul-07,40000
M003,AJIT,D003,8-Mar-07,8-Sep-07,80000
M010,Nalini,D007,15-Apr-07,15-Oct-07,9999
M007,Usha,D003,17-Apr-07,17-Oct-07,70000
M004,SHARVARI,D004,28-Mar-07,28-Mar-08,120000
M006,Rohan,D004,12-Apr-07,12-Apr-08,130000
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kudos for adding your efforts/code and sample of input. Kindly do add samples of output also in your question to make it more clear, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: expected outcome is ascending order of date in 5th column.As shown in my latest edit

Comment: Where's the awk command though? We might able to fix that.

Comment: @Darkman I have tried it but does not give expected result.As you can see in my edit

Comment: You should have included in your example some lines with the same date in the 5th field so we could see the order you want those output. Do you REALLY not want the header line to be output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```bash
tail -n+2 Joining_date.txt | sed -E 's/^(([^,]+,){4})([0-9]-)/\10\3/' | LC_ALL=C sort -t ',' -k 5.8n -k 5.4M -k 5.1n
```

- `tail -n+2` -- Get from 2nd line to the end.
- `sed -E 's/^(([^,]+,){4})([0-9]-)/\10\3/` -- Prepend a zero to the day of 5th field into two-digit day.
- `sort -t ',' -k 5.8n -k 5.4M -k 5.1n`

  - `-t ','` -- Set a field delimeter (`,`) for `sort`
  - `-k 5.8n` -- Sort by numeric years first.
  - `-k 5.4M` -- Sort by months next.
  - `-k 5.1n` -- Sort by numeric days.

Comment: I have got your logic for date sort but  regex exp you wrote is diff to understand..What does /\10\3/ represent in sed expression?

Comment: `\1` is for group 1, `0` is a literal zero and `\3` is a group 3. You may want to play a bit like this: `echo 'M008,Anjali,D002,2-Apr-07,2-Jul-07,40000' | sed -E 's/^(([^,]+,){4})([0-9]-)/\1xxx\3xxx/'`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Applying [the DSU idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367) using any awk+sort+cut:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
    {
        split($5,d)
        mth = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",d[2])+2)/3
        datec=csprintf("%04d%02d%02d", d[3], mth, d[1])
        print (NR>1), date, NR, $0
    }
' file |
sort -n -k1,2 -k3,3 |
cut -f4-
M_ID,M_NAME,DEPT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,Salary
M001,Richa,D001,27-Jan-07,27-Feb-07,150000
M002,Nitin,D002,16-Feb-07,16-May-07,40000
M003,AJIT,D003,8-Mar-07,8-Sep-07,70000
M004,SHARVARI,D004,28-Mar-07,28-Mar-08,120000
M005,ADITYA,D002,27-Apr-07,27-Jul-07,40000
M006,Rohan,D004,12-Apr-07,12-Apr-08,130000
M007,Usha,D003,17-Apr-07,17-Oct-07,70000
M008,Anjali,D002,2-Apr-07,2-Jul-07,40000
M009,Yash,D006,11-Apr-07,11-Jul-07,85000
M010,Nalini,D007,15-Apr-07,15-Oct-07,9999
```

The above ensures the header line will be printed first even if it has a number in the 5th field, and all lines with the same date in the 5th field will be printed in the original input order. Just change the 2nd `{` to `NR>1 {` if you really don't want the header line printed.