# Sort on 3, 31 and months consequently

Tags: sorting, awk, sed

I have these lines in a file:

```
Oct 29 23:14:39 
Oct 30 19:45:15 
Oct 31 13:15:19 
Nov 1  10:34:15
Nov 2  18:39:20
Nov 3  12:34:59 
Nov 4  16:34:59 
Nov 5  20:34:59
```

When I run `sort -r -k2` it gives me the following:

```
 Nov 5
 Nov 4
 Nov 3
 Oct 31
 Oct 30
 Oct 29
 Nov 2
 Nov 1
```

How do I get it like so:

```
Nov 5
Nov 4
Nov 3
Nov 2
Nov 1
Oct 31
Oct 30
Oct 29
```

Would appreciate any pointers, comments, advices at all. Do I also need to sort on months in reverse order? How? -M -r?

Comment: please verify your inputs, command and outputs and update the question; I don't see how the command you've provided can a) switch the positioning of the day and month and b) remove the time

Comment: the time is not removed, it is there. I simply did not type it in for clarity.

Comment: again, update the question with the *complete* wrong & correct outputs; leaving out some data does not provide clarity but rather confusion as it now looks like you want to remove the times

Comment: if there are two rows with `Nov 5`, are they to be further sorted by time? is the input file already sorted by date and time ...in which case all you want to do is sort the file in reverse order?

Comment: @markp-fuso my question was answered hours ago. The answers were just awesome and excellent! Thank you for keeping an eye on it too. Appreciate.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74326091/1745001) by starting with this. That doesn't get you close to solving the rest of your question (starting output on or after a specific date) and once you [solve the rest of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74328429/1745001) you don't need this.

Answer (score 1):

This works well!

```bash
sort -k1Mr -r -k2nr file.txt
```

**file.txt content**

```
Oct 6  20:34:59
Oct 29 23:14:39
Oct 30 19:45:15
Oct 31 13:15:19
Nov 1  10:34:15
Nov 2  18:39:20
Nov 3  12:34:59
Nov 4  16:34:59
Nov 5  20:34:59
```

**Output:**

```
Nov 5  20:34:59
Nov 4  16:34:59
Nov 3  12:34:59
Nov 2  18:39:20
Nov 1  10:34:15
Oct 31 13:15:19
Oct 30 19:45:15
Oct 29 23:14:39
Oct 6  20:34:59
```

NOTE:
The following answers fail to sort the entry `Oct 6  20:34:59` if exists.

```
sort -k1,1 -k2r,2
```

```
sort -rM
```

Comment: Oh, good catch on `Oct 6`.

Comment: yes.. this one is more elaborated

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sort for `-M`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dates are sorted in the file, just reverse the line order:

```
tac file
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```bash
sort -k1Mr,1 -k2r,2
```

month-sorted by field #1 reversely, then sorted by field #2 reversely

```
Nov 5  20:34:59
Nov 4  16:34:59
Nov 3  12:34:59
Nov 2  18:39:20
Nov 1  10:34:15
Oct 31 13:15:19
Oct 30 19:45:15
Oct 29 23:14:39
```

Edit:

A key specification like `-k2` means to take all the fields from 2 to the end of the line into account.

To sort by a single column, use `-k2,2` as the key specification. This means to use the fields from #2 to #2, i.e. only the second field.

```bash
man sort

   -k, --key=KEYDEF
          sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
   ...

   KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where
   F is a field number and C a character position in the field; both are
   origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.
```

Comment: Hmm.. nice, thank you so much! Could you please, explain the coma after 1 and 2? -k1,1 and -k2r,2 What is that for? Sort by field #1 first and then sort by field #2 second?

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain the comma :)

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sort for `-M`.

Answer (score 0):

The arrangement of the fields is lucky, in that the primary one comes first, and the secondary one second (and the rest of the line doesn't matter because you have at most one entry per day). But your example has only `Oct` and `Nov`, and I don't think you ought to rely on that. If you add e.g. `Aug 7` you'll need a more robust solution. I suggest:

```
sort -rM
```

That is, sort in the default way (by the first field, then by the second), treat any month abbreviation found as a month abbreviation, and reverse the whole thing.

**EDIT:** This is incorrect. @SaSkY's answer is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you! Looks simple. I knew it was simple but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Well, in fact there could be many entries per day. It just depends on a day. Would that be a problem with `sort -rM`then?

Comment: @Dennis: That depends; what do you want the code to do in that case?

Comment: I just need it to be sorted in reverse order (backwards), that's all there is to it. Either one entry per day or multiple entries per day. It's fine as long as it can sort it. It does not need to do anything else at all. Thanks

Comment: @Dennis: SaSkY's answer is the correct one.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sort for `-M`.