# Rearrange rows of a csv based on a column value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to rearrange the rows in a csv based on the key given in 5th column of my data.
My data looks like this (**test.csv**):

```
Col A,Col B,Col C,Col D,Col E
A,Data 1,Category 1,Name 1,C
B,Data 2,Category 2,Name 2,C
C,Data 3,Category 3,Name 3,C
D,Data 4,Category 4,Name 4,C
E,Data 5,Category 5,Name 5,C
F,Data 6,Category 6,Name 6,C
```

I am trying to rearrange it so that the row containing the key value in first column is at top (in this case the key value is **C**)

Desired output :

```
Col A,Col B,Col C,Col D,Col E
C,Data 3,Category 3,Name 3,C
A,Data 1,Category 1,Name 1,C
B,Data 2,Category 2,Name 2,C
D,Data 4,Category 4,Name 4,C
E,Data 5,Category 5,Name 5,C
F,Data 6,Category 6,Name 6,C
```

I have written the below code and also getting the desired result doing so i am generating two temporary files , just wondering if there is a better solution :

```
sed 1d test.csv > input.csv 
key=`awk -F"," -v 'OFS=,' '{ print $5}' input.csv | uniq`
awk -F"," -v 'OFS=,' '{if($1 == "'$key'") print}' input.csv > temp.csv
cat temp.csv input.csv > temp2.csv

awk '!seen[$0]++' temp2.csv > output.csv

sed -i '1iCol A,Col B,Col C,Col D,Col E' output.csv
```

Please help !

Comment: Please, post the sample data with the related expected output in text.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Also, as this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some attempt first. Thanks.

Comment: have a look now, dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```bash
awk -F ',' '
    !seen[$0]++ {
        if ( $1 == $5 || NR == 1 )
            print
        else
            arr[++n] = $0
    }
    END { for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print arr[i] }
' input.csv > output.csv
```

That'll bufferize the non-matching lines and output them at the end.

output

```
Col A,Col B,Col C,Col D,Col E
C,Data 3,Category 3,Name 3,C
A,Data 1,Category 1,Name 1,C
B,Data 2,Category 2,Name 2,C
D,Data 4,Category 4,Name 4,C
E,Data 5,Category 5,Name 5,C
F,Data 6,Category 6,Name 6,C
```

Comment: That will save the whole of the input except for 2 lines n memory twice, once in `seen[]` and then again in `arr[]`, so YMMV for very large input. I actually don't understand why you're using `!seen[$0]++` to remove duplicate lines - I know it shows up in the OPs code but I expect that's to clean up damage done by other parts of that code, I don't see anything in the requirements in the question suggesting that's desired.

Comment: @EdMorton You're right, removing the dups might not be required, but if it is, I don't know how to make the code more efficient without using `PROCINFO` or temp files.

Comment: I'd probably apply [DSU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367) if that were the case but I'd need to see an actual question about that with a relevant [mcve] to know for sure. I really think the ops code is only removing dups with `awk '!seen[$0]++' temp2.csv` because the preceding line of `cat temp.csv input.csv > temp2.csv` is creating those dups though.

Comment: @EdMorton you are right, i am using !seen[$0]++ just to remove the dups as i would be using the file for further use and it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
(NR == 1) || f {
    print
    next
}
$1 == $5 {
    print $0 buf
    f = 1
}
{ buf = buf ORS $0 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk test.csv
Col A,Col B,Col C,Col D,Col E
C,Data 3,Category 3,Name 3,C
A,Data 1,Category 1,Name 1,C
B,Data 2,Category 2,Name 2,C
D,Data 4,Category 4,Name 4,C
E,Data 5,Category 5,Name 5,C
F,Data 6,Category 6,Name 6,C
```

The above will only save the lines up to the matching line in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/^([^\n]*\n)(.*\n)(([[:alpha:]])[^\n]*\4\n)/\1\3\2/woutput.csv' input_file
$ cat output.csv
Col A,Col B,Col C,Col D,Col E
C,Data 3,Category 3,Name 3,C
A,Data 1,Category 1,Name 1,C
B,Data 2,Category 2,Name 2,C
D,Data 4,Category 4,Name 4,C
E,Data 5,Category 5,Name 5,C
F,Data 6,Category 6,Name 6,C
```